# Writing to stdin for homebrew-piping

Tags: c, pipe, stdin

I'm writing a small program to mimic the Unix piping system (e.g. "`cat file1.txt | grep keyword | wc`").

I can manage to collect the output of the programs from stdout using `dup2()` and pipes but I can't work out how to feed it on to the next process.

At first I thought it was simple, just something like:

```
write(stdin, buffer, buffer_size);
```

but that's not working for me. There is a lot of information out there about stdout but not nearly as much about stdin.

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: You want to `read` from stdin not `write` to it.

Comment: @GWW do i? but dont i want to *write* into it?
i might just be struggling to visualize this, cos if i *read* from the output im just assuming you *write* to the input...

Comment: In process one (ie cat) you want to write to stdout, then in process two (ie. grep) you want to read from stdin and then write to stdout, and finally in process 3 (wc) you want to read from stdin and write to stdout

Comment: We should, I assume, ignore the fact that `grep -c keyword file1.txt` probably produces the answer you are after.  It isn't quite identical; the pipeline will print the characters and words in the lines matching, but `grep keyword file1.txt | wc` is equivalent.

Comment: Do your `dup2(pipe[1], 1)` etc. after a `fork`.  (Also, what exactly is a "homebrew" pipe?  Are you piping beer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't be doing any reading or writing; it will just be plumbing (sorting out the pipes).

You will create two pipes and two children.  The first child will run the `cat` command; the second the `grep` command, and the parent will run the `wc` program.  Since there are no pathnames for the programs, the code will use `execvp()`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...);
static void exec_head(char **args, int *p1, int *p2);
static void exec_tail(char **args, int *p1, int *p2);
static void exec_middle(char **args, int *p1, int *p2);
static void exec_cmd(char **args, int *p1, int *p2);

int main(void)
{
    char *cmd1[] = { "cat", "file1.txt", 0 };
    char *cmd2[] = { "grep", "keyword", 0 };
    char *cmd3[] = { "wc", 0 };
    int pipe12[2];
    int pipe23[2];
    pid_t pid1;
    pid_t pid2;

    if (pipe(pipe12) != 0 || pipe(pipe23) != 0)
        err_exit("Failed to create pipes");

    if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to fork (child1)");
    else if (pid1 == 0)
        exec_head(cmd1, pipe12, pipe23);
    else if ((pid2 = fork()) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to fork (child2):");
    else if (pid2 == 0)
        exec_middle(cmd2, pipe12, pipe23);
    else
        exec_tail(cmd3, pipe12, pipe23);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
    return(-1);
}

/* Execute head process in pipeline */
/* Close both pipes in p2; connect write end of pipe p1 to stdout */
static void exec_head(char **args, int *p1, int *p2)
{
    if (dup2(p1[1], 1) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to duplicate file descriptor to stdout (%s)", args[0]);
    exec_cmd(args, p1, p2);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

/* Execute tail process in pipeline */
/* Close both pipes in p1; connect read end of p2 to standard input */
static void exec_tail(char **args, int *p1, int *p2)
{
    if (dup2(p2[0], 0) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to duplicate file descriptor to stdin (%s)", args[0]);
    exec_cmd(args, p1, p2);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

/* Execute middle command in pipeline */
/* Connect read end of p1 to stdin; connect write end of p2 to stdout */
static void exec_middle(char **args, int *p1, int *p2)
{
    if (dup2(p1[0], 0) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to duplicate file descriptor to stdin (%s)", args[0]);
    if (dup2(p2[1], 1) < 0)
        err_exit("Failed to duplicate file descriptor to stdout (%s)", args[0]);
    exec_cmd(args, p1, p2);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

/* Close all descriptors for pipes p1, p2 and exec command */
static void exec_cmd(char **args, int *p1, int *p2)
{
    close(p1[0]);
    close(p1[1]);
    close(p2[0]);
    close(p2[1]);
    execvp(args[0], args);
    err_exit("Failed to execute %s", args[0]);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

static void err_exit(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int errnum = errno;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (errnum != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, ":%d: %s", errnum, strerror(errnum));
    putc('\n', stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

With a bit more work on refactoring, and handling the pipes carefully, you could eliminate the `exec_head()`, `exec_tail()` and `exec_middle()` functions (specify descriptor to become stdin, or -1 if it should leave stdin alone; specify descriptor to become stdout, or -1 if it should leave stdout alone), and you can streamline the pipe handling by using a single array of 4 and modifying the calls to the `pipe()` system call accordingly.  That then becomes generalizable without much difficulty...  The code should probably be using `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` instead of 0 and 1 for the second argument to `dup2()`.  There aren't defined constants for the read and write ends of a pipe (`enum { PIPE_READ, PIPE_WRITE };` might be useful here).

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you mean that you want to execute the command `cat file1.txt | grep keyword | wc` from within your program.

You can do this by setting up some pipes for in between the programs with `pipe()`.
Then `fork` a few times for each program you want to execute.
In the different forked processes set the `stdin` and `stdout` to the correct endings of the created pipes.
When everything is setup, you can call `exec()` to execute the different programs like `cat`, `grep` and `wc` with the correct parameters.

Your program can than just read from the pipe after the `wc` program to get the final output.